# Adapt a dictionary depending on the values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following problem: I create a dictionary in which the keys are IDs (0 to N) and the values are list of one or more numbers.

```
D = dict()
D[0] = [1]
D[1] = [2]
D[2] = [0]
```

OR:

```
D = dict()
D[0] = [1, 2]
D[1] = [1, 2]
D[2] = [0]
```

When the list stored in dictionary has more than one value, it always means that this list is present under 2 different keys. What I now want is to convert both dict into this:

```
D = dict()
D[0] = 1
D[1] = 2
D[2] = 0
```

For the first one, it's simple, the function will simply replace the values of the dict by the first value in the list:

```
def transform_dict(D):
    for key, value in D.items():
        D[key] = value[0]
    return D
```

However, in the second case, the function must assign one of the key with one of the value, and the second with another. For instance, the key "0" can be assign the value "1" or "2"; and the key "1" will be assign the other one.

I am struggling with this simple problem, and I don't see a way to do this efficiently. Do you have any idea?

**EDIT: Explanation n°2**

The initial dict can have the following format:

```
D[key1] = [val1]
D[key2] = [val2]
D[key3] = [val3, val4]
D[key4] = [val3, val4]
```

If a list of values is composed of more than one element, it means that a second key exist within the dictionnary with the same list of values (key3 and key4).

The goal is to transform this dict into:

```
D[key1] = val1
D[key2] = val2
D[key3] = val3
D[key4] = val4
```

Where val3 and val4 are attributed to key3 and key4 in whatever way (I don't care which one goes with which key).

**EDIT2: Examples:**

```
# Input dict
D[0] = [7]
D[1] = [5]
D[2] = [4]
D[3] = [1, 2, 3]
D[4] = [6, 8]
D[5] = [1, 2, 3]
D[6] = [1, 2, 3]
D[7] = [6, 8]

#Output
D[0] = 7
D[1] = 5
D[2] = 4
D[3] = 1
D[4] = 6
D[5] = 2
D[6] = 3
D[7] = 8
```

Comment: Dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys if that's what you want?

Comment: @Chris_Rands No, the keys are unique: 0 to N. However, sometime a value is the same for 2 keys (or more!), for instance, `[1, 2]` is present for both the key 0 and 1. The question is then, how to transform the dict into a new one where all keys only point to one value based on the rules explained above.

Comment: i don't understand your problem really, but look up `collections.defaultdict`

Comment: @Chris_Rands Probably one of the reason I struggle to figure it out too, I can't really explain it well. Defaultdict won't help. The point is to transform the dictionnary into a new one. I'll try to rework a bit the question in an edit.

Comment: Explaining the problem clearly will give you half the solution :)

Comment: Just give multiple examples of inputs and desired outputs and likely the problem will reveal itself!

Comment: @Chris_Rands the edit should help, I could probably write a function doing that, but it will be a bit messy and I'm quite sure an efficient method exist for this.

Comment: Based on your edits, do you care that `val3` is going with `key3` or could also go with say `key5`? i.e. is it required that `keyN` contains a value it used to have within the list?

Comment: @norok2 Yes it is require! val3 can go either with key3 or key4; and val4 will go with the other one.

Comment: so if the list has `M` elements, the input dict will have exactly `M` keys associated with it?

Comment: @norok2 Yes, if one the list has M elements, it means that the dictionnary will contain M keys (among others) which will point to the same list of M elements.

Comment: @norok2 Someone getting it :) ^^'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this is the most efficient, but it seems a way of doing it:

```
in_dict = dict()
in_dict[0] = [7]
in_dict[1] = [5]
in_dict[2] = [4]
in_dict[3] = [1, 2, 3]
in_dict[4] = [6, 8]
in_dict[5] = [1, 2, 3]
in_dict[6] = [1, 2, 3]
in_dict[7] = [6, 8]

out_dict = dict()
out_dict[0] = 7
out_dict[1] = 5
out_dict[2] = 4
out_dict[3] = 1
out_dict[4] = 6
out_dict[5] = 2
out_dict[6] = 3
out_dict[7] = 8

def weird_process(mapping):
    result = dict()
    for key, val in mapping.items():
        if len(val) == 1:
            result[key] = val[0]
        elif key not in result:  # was: `else:`
            # find other keys having the same value
            matching_keys = [k for k, v in mapping.items() if v == val]
            for i, k in enumerate(matching_keys):
                result[k] = val[i]
    return result


weird_process(in_dict) == out_dict
# True
```

*EDIT: I have simplified the code a little bit.*

*EDIT2: I have improved the efficiency by skipping elements that have been already processed*

---

**EDIT3**

An even faster approach would be to use a temporary copy of the input keys to reduce the inner looping by consuming the input as soon as it gets used:

```
def weird_process(mapping):
    unseen = set(mapping.keys())
    result = dict()
    for key, val in mapping.items():
        if len(val) == 1:
            result[key] = val[0]
        elif key not in result:
            # find other keys having the same value
            matching_keys = [k for k in unseen if mapping[k] == val]
            for i, k in enumerate(matching_keys):
                result[k] = val[i]
                unseen.remove(k)
    return result
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to understand this weird process :) Indeed, it does the job done, I was actually writing something similar in the end... Well If we don't see any better way of doing this, maybe there isn't! Thanks :)

Comment: Main reason I was looking for something more efficient is because this solution is incapsulated into a O(n²) loop, thus the program becomes O(n^4).

Comment: you could keep track of already visited keys... actually using `result` for that, which already contains the relevant information (see edit2). I am not sure you can get much faster than this.

Comment: You can perhaps get a bit faster by looping only through the unseen keys (see edit3)

Answer (score 2):

You can also create a class which behaves likes a dictionary. That way you don't need any additional functions to "clean" the dictionary afterwards but rather solve it on the fly :)

How it works:

- We extend `collections.abc.Mapping` and overwrite the standard dictionary functions `__getitem__`, `__setitem__` and `__iter__`. We use `self._storage` to save the actual dictionary.
- We use a second dictionary `_unresolved` to keep track of the keys which haven't been resolved yet. In the example above it for example has the entry `(1, 2, 3): [4, 5]`.
- We use a helper function `_resolve()` that checks if the `len((1,2,3)) == len([4,5])`. On the moment you assign `D[6]` this lengths are equal, and the items are assigned to `self._storage`.

Tried to add comments in the code.

```
from collections.abc import Mapping
from collections import defaultdict 

class WeirdDict(Mapping):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        self._storage = dict()  # the actual dictionary returned

        self._unresolved = defaultdict(list)  # a reversed mapping of the unresolved items
        for key, value in dict(*args, **kw).items():
            self._unresolved_vals[value].append(key)

        self._resolve()

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._storage[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        """ Setter. """
        if type(val) == int:
            self._storage[key] = val 
        elif len(val) == 1:
            self._storage[key] = val[0]
        elif key not in self._storage:
            self._unresolved[tuple(val)].append(key)
            self._resolve()

    def _resolve(self):
        """ Helper function - checks if any keys can be resolved """
        resolved = set()
        for val, keys in self._unresolved.items():  # left to resolve
            if len(val) == len(keys):  # if we can resolve (count exhausted)
                for i, k in enumerate(keys):
                    self._storage[k] = val[i]
                    resolved.add(val)
        # Remove from todo list              
        for val in resolved:
            del self._unresolved[val]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._storage)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._storage)
```

And then start with:

```
D = WeirdDict()

D[0] = [7]
D[1] = 5
D[2] = (4)
D[3] = (1, 2, 3)
D[4] = (6, 8)
D[5] = (1, 2, 3)
D[6] = (1, 2, 3)
D[7] = [6, 8]

# Try this for different output 
D[7]  # gives 8
```

Comment: I am not sure if this would work. Could you provide a some working example? In my opinion, you cannot correctly implement the `_resolve()` method until you know all the keys of the dictionary.

Comment: Of course its difficult to see the exact problem from the question. But as far as I understand it, you can resolve `(6, 8)` of the example on the moment you have two keys pointing to this value.

Comment: :) Added some extra comments.

Comment: I agree that you do not need all the keys and if one is going to build the dict incrementally, this is actually a smart approach.